# How To Add the User Defined Name Space in the User Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have 2 class file stored in the User Control Folder which has namespace X and 1 class file in the App_code folder which has namespace Y and my Project is web site type project.I have my user control defined in the User Control folder. How can I use the namespace X and Y respectively in my User Control ?

I tried using normally by 'using' keyword ,but it throws an error stating it could not be found. I also tried to keep the user control name space X so at least I can use namespace X but no luck.

Comment: Can you show the code and tell us what you want and how you want ? What did you try for that and what issue you are facing/

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya The Class File are the Composite Controls I am creating and I have already mentioned what I tried and issues I am facing.